# i am creating quiz and need to assign a csv file to a variable

Tags: python

```
import csv
column_2 = []
f = open("easyquestion.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    column_2.append(row[1])
f.close()
print column_2
```

I am creating a quiz using python where I am required to assign a CSV file to a variable for further use, however, i am unable to do it, could you please help me and feel free to give any advice, thank you in advance but then this shows an error

```
 & "C:/Program Files (x86)/Python37-32/python.exe" c:/Users/tarang/Desktop/pyt/try.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & "C:/Program Files (x86)/Python37-32/python.exe" c:/Users/tarang/Desktop/pyt/try.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Define your file mode :  like this `f=open("easyquestion.csv","a+")`

Comment: and by the way use `with open(filename,mode):` statement instead.

Comment: @SunilKhatri Why use `a+` mode when the file is only being read?

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it still does not work, could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

it should be print(column_2) instead of print column_2 as you are using python 3.
following should work

```
import csv
column_2 = []
with open("easyquestion.csv","r") as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        column_2.append(row[0])

print(column_2)
```